# Spring Data JPA & Liquibase composite key many to many

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I'm working with Spring Data JPA using Liquibase, i have two classes , the first one with simple key and the second one with composite key, (many to many relationship)

The First Class :

```
public class Person {


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "person_adress", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "adress_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "country") })
    private List<Adress> adresses;

// Other attributes
}
```

Second class :

```
public class Adress {


@EmbeddedId
    private AdressId adressId; // contains adress_id and country as composite key

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "adresses")
    private List<Person> persons;
// Other attributes 

}
```

Liquibase file :

```
<changeSet id="......." author="........">
        <createTable tableName="person_adress">
            <column name="person_id" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="adress_id" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="country" type="varchar(2)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
        <addUniqueConstraint
            columnNames="country, adress_id,person_id"
            constraintName="keey"
            tableName="person_adress" />
    </changeSet>
```

when i call this service :

```
adress.add(ListOfPersons);
adressRepository.save(adress);
```

adress was been persisted and a list of persons too , in postgresql , but the problem that person_adress table still empty

Answer (score -1):

You can find the same approach (many-to-many with extra column) on the following link.

Instead of using a @ManyToMany the author use a bidirecitional @OneToMany defining an extra object to represent the correlation object with and @EmbeddedId (PostTag and PostTagId)

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score -2):

you can see this exemple for mapping many to many:
https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-spring-data-jpa-postgresql-and-liquiba

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.  See more advice on writing good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).